# Possible output of the following program fragment?

Tags: c++, c, getchar, putchar

```
for(i=getchar();; i=getchar())
if(i=='x')
break;
else putchar(i);
```

Answer is : mi

Can someone explain this piece of code ?(MCQ Question)

Answer (score 4):

This question can be solved by eliminating incorrect answer. This fragments prints character and exits loop if the character is an `x`. So the program would not output an `x`.

Any output string that doesn't contain `x` is possible. In your MCQ, possibly `mi` is the only option with `x` and all other options contain `x` somewhere in the string making them incorrect answer.

If input is "mix....", output would be "mi". Below is your loop unrolled.

```
getchar() -> m -> else -> print m  /* First getchar */
getchar() -> i -> else -> print i  /* Second getchar */
getchar() -> x -> if -> break      /* Second getchar */
```

Comment: But input is not mentioned in this ques ? I have copied this question as it is .

Comment: @Abdul , It is possible to determine the input as GyaptiJain did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=getchar();; i=getchar())
if(i=='x')
break;
else putchar(i);
```

your Code will keep on running till it encounter 'x' so whatever input you give, it will read character by character as you have used getchar() function..

- If character is 'x' then break the loop.
- else print character.

like, If the input is

> *sparx*

output will be

> spar

The for loop

```
 for(i=getchar();; i=getchar())
```

and syntax and structure of the for loop is

```
for ( variable initialization; condition; variable update )
```

as i = getchar() will read char 'i' it is ok. next there is no condition and final in updating you are again reading a character so it a infinite loop.

Loop will terminate only when it will encounter `'x'` as the statement

```
if(i=='x')
break;
```

Otherwise it will keep on printing the character.

```
else putchar(i);
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/Dhu9Xo).

Hope it helps!!